# How I can auto end specific process?

Tags: memory, process

How can I auto end a specific process when it reaches 400 MB RAM?
And how do I change it back after I do that?
Is there any program or script or anything ?

Comment: which operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows Server Operating System you can use the [Windows System Resource Manager (WSRM)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mrsnrub/archive/2009/12/08/windows-system-resource-manager-wsrm-does-exactly-what-it-says-on-the-tin.aspx) to stop applications if they reach a limit:

[image]

Comment: these app in windows server 2003 and higher as a main function i need it 2 be used on windows 7 can it be .... is there is any similar prog can do the same progress for me ........ thnx any way

Comment: this only works for Server.try if this 3rd party tool does have the option to close apps: http://bitsum.com/processlasso/